# JavaScript Toggle class

Tags: javascript

```
'use strict'

const switcher = document.querySelector('.btn');
console.log(switcher);

switcher.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.body.classList.toggle('dark-theme');

    let className = document.body.className;
    if (className == "light-theme") {
        this.textContent = "Dark";
    }
    else {
       this.textContent = "Light";
    }
});
```

Not sure how the toggle works. How is when I click the button the background changes back to the light-theme when the script doesn't even specify to change back to light-theme?

Answer (score 3):

It's the `document.body.classList.toggle('dark-theme');`.

If that class exists, it is removed. If that class doesn't exist, it is added.

Your button changes the HTML from

```
<body class="light-theme">
```

to

```
<body class="light-theme dark-theme">
```

and back again.

Using CSS rules, if two rulesets with the same specificity are declared, and one is declared *below* the other, the one below will take precedence if both apply to an element. So

```
.light-theme {
  /* rules */
}
.dark-theme {
  /* rules */
}
```

will mean that if an element has `dark-theme` and `light-theme`, `dark-theme`'s rules will override any duplicate styles applied by `light-theme`.

Comment: A bit of a nitpicky question maybe, but does this mean that it first creates "light-theme" and then "dark-theme" on top of it, so that the "light-theme" isn't visible anymore? If so, if these themes are very big, that might give some performance issues, wouldn't it?

Comment: I guess it's not impossible, but I've never heard of this sort of thing being an actual problem people have run into. There are almost certainly better parts of the code to focus on optimizing. Perhaps toggling one of the themes off completely when toggling the other on would help - but it may not, and you're likely to see absolutely no difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Theme</title>
   
</head>
<body class="light-theme">


  <div>
    <button type="button" class="btn">Dark</button>
  </div>
      
      
 
  <script type="text/javascript">

'use strict'

const switcher = document.querySelector('.btn');
console.log(switcher);

switcher.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.body.classList.toggle('dark-theme');
    document.body.classList.toggle('light-theme');

    let className = document.body.className;
    if (className == "light-theme") {
        this.textContent = "Dark";
    }
    else {
       this.textContent = "Light";
    }
});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```